# How can I upload nodejs and npm executables to artifactory

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, artifactory

We have a company proxy that prevents me from using the maven-frontend-plugin as it is.

The problem is that to fetch npm and bower dependencies we use an internal Artifactory so we should not have any proxy settings for that. But the actual executables are fetched directly thus to fetch them we need the proxy. And the frontend-plugin doesn't seem to support exceptions for specific domains.

So is there an easy way to upload npm and nodejs executables to our internal artifactory so that we can skip the proxy altogether? Or another way of solving this?

**Edit**

I add the solution here for ease since I needed to modify the answer I approved below.

Set up two remote repositories in Artifactory, one to nodejs (`https://nodejs.org/dist/`) and one to npm (`https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/`).

The edit your maven-frontend-plugin configuration:

```
<execution>
    <!-- optional: you don't really need execution ids,
    but it looks nice in your build log. -->
    <id>install node and npm</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>v0.12.1</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>2.14.1</npmVersion>
        <!-- use the URL for the repository you created in step 1 -->
        <nodeDownloadRoot>https://artifactory.my company.com/artifactory/nodejs.dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
        <npmDownloadRoot>https://artifactory.my company.com/artifactory/npm.dist/</npmDownloadRoot>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

It was possible to only use only the nodejs repo (but then npm is available only to version 1.4.9) Change npmDownloadRoot to:

`<npmDownloadRoot>https://artifactory.my company.com/artifactory/nodejs.dist/npm/</npmDownloadRoot>`

And don't forget to remove the proxy settings from your maven `settings.xml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install the node and npm executables from Artifactory you should:

1. Create a new repository in Artifactory which will be used for the node and npm distributions. If you are using Artifactory 4.x, you should create a remote[generic repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-GenericRepositories) (for older versions just create a remote repository).
   This repository should proxy the node and npm distribution server - https://nodejs.org/dist/
   Another option is creating a local repository and manually deploying the node and npm distribution into it while keeping the same layout as https://nodejs.org/dist/
2. Configure the frontend-maven-plugin to use Artifactory instead of the default. This should be done by setting the `downloadRoot` property, for example:

```xml
<execution>
    <!-- optional: you don't really need execution ids,
    but it looks nice in your build log. -->
    <id>install node and npm</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>v0.10.18</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>1.3.8</npmVersion>
        <!-- use the URL for the repository you created in step 1 -->
        <downloadRoot>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo-id/</downloadRoot>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

For more info see [installing node and npm](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#installing-node-and-npm) in the plugin documentation

Comment: Great this was as easy as it should be, the only annoying thing left is to get a more recent version of npm (seems like the nodejs dist repo only have it up to version 1.4.9). You don't happen to know a url for that? Googling gives me tons of irrelevant hits.

Answer (score 1):

Using Artifactory for both proxying npm registry and hosting your own npms and executables is a good decision, your admins did well.

For deploying any file to Artifactory from the UI you can use the Deploy tab (Artifactory 3) or the Deploy button in the Artifact Browser (Artifactory 4).

Another option (probably, preferable) will be using `npm publish`. The [User Guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Repositories#NpmRepositories-NpmPublish%28DeployingPackages%29) gives very details instructions on how to do that. If you're using Artifactory 4, you can also click on the Set Me Up button in the Artifact Browser screen:
[image: Artifactory Set Me Up - how to deploy npm package]

Third option, which works for any file, will be [a simple PUT HTTP request](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact).

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. We do not yet have the executables in Artifactory. The question was actually if there was an easy way to upload the executables to it (Artifactory). I happen to be the admin of it, and I can't find anything about how to get them and their dependencies published in our Artifactory.

Comment: My answer was about how to deploy artifacts to Artifactory.